# Python - Downloading page's HTML when it shares a URL with multiple other pages

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium, python-requests

I'm currently writing a program with python that will scrape data from my university's class registration website so I will be notified when a seat in a certain class opens up.

I'm using selenium to navigate the various drop-down menus and text input boxes. I can successfully get to the page I want to be on, but from page to page, the URL's are not unique with regard to their content.

For example, the page where you choose your desired subject is https://wl11gp.neu.edu/udcprod8/NEUCLSS.p_class_select. If I were to then pick, say, English Writing the URL becomes https://wl11gp.neu.edu/udcprod8/NEUCLSS.p_class_search.

This is the same whether I pick English Writing, Math, Biology, or any subject. As a result, if I use the requests module to download the page's HTML, I receive a 404 error message.

Is there some method for downloading the HTML of the current page without providing a URL?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If you inspect the html of p_class_select, you'll see a form with action="NEUCLSS.p_class_search" and method="post". That's what you need to simulate: a POST request to p_class_search with the required data, **not** a download/GET request.

Comment: Interesting, I'm just starting out with python so I'll have to read up on POST requests and how to manipulate the HTML in that way. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @Prunechi have you tried `driver.current_url`?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would format the data differently but to get you going quick here's how you would do it with python-requests.

```
import requests

# all data here is the default except sel_subj=ACC
requests.post("https://wl11gp.neu.edu/udcprod8/NEUCLSS.p_class_search", data="sel_day=dummy&STU_TERM_IN=201754&sel_subj=dummy&sel_attr=dummy&sel_schd=dummy&sel_camp=dummy&sel_insm=dummy&sel_ptrm=dummy&sel_levl=dummy&sel_instr=dummy&sel_seat=dummy&p_msg_code=You+must+select+a+term.&sel_crn=&sel_subj=ACC&sel_crse=&sel_title=&sel_attr=%25&sel_levl=%25&sel_schd=%25&sel_insm=%25&sel_from_cred=&sel_to_cred=&sel_camp=%25&sel_ptrm=%25&sel_instr=%25&begin_hh=0&begin_mi=0&begin_ap=a&end_hh=0&end_mi=0&end_ap=a")
```